# References for Modular Decomposition

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

What are good papers/books to better understand the power of Modular Decomposition and its properties?

I'm particularly interested in algorithmic aspects of Modular Decomposition. I have heard that it is possible to find a Modular Decomposition of a graph in linear time. Is there are an relatively simple algorithm for that? What about a not so efficient but simpler algorithm?

Comment: what is a modular decomposition ?

Comment: @Suresh: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_decomposition

Comment: @David Thanks ! I didn't know about them and they sound neat.

Comment: @Nathann Cohen would probably be the best person to comment on this, since he integrated the linear-time modular decomposition algorithm into SAGE.  Fabien de Montgolfier's C code: http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~fm/algos/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look at [A Simple Linear-Time Modular Decomposition Algorithm for Graphs, Using Order Extension, SWAT 2004](http://springerlink.metapress.com/openurl.asp?genre=article&issn=0302-9743&volume=3111&spage=187) and [Linear-time modular decomposition of directed graphs, Disc. Appl. Math. 2005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2004.02.017) for the simplest known linear-time algorithms on undirected and directed graph respectively.

The problem has mainly attracted theoretical interest and the algorithms developed so far are relatively complex. I do not think that has been a sustained effort towards an algorithm that is actually amenable to be implemented (i.e. "not so efficient but simpler").

FYI, the first linear-time algorithms for undirected graphs have been [A New Linear Algorithm for Modular Decomposition. CAAP 1994](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0017474) and [Linear-Time Modular Decomposition and Efficient Transitive Orientation of Comparability Graphs](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/314464.314641).

Comment: I like "not so efficient but simpler" as a motto for doing experimental algorithms work :)

Comment: Author implementation http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~fm/algos/index.html.

Answer (score 17):

There is a recent survey

Habib and Paul (2010). [A survey of the algorithmic aspects of modular decomposition.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cosrev.2010.01.001) Computer Science Review 4(1): 41-59 (2010)

that you should check out.

Answer (score 7):

Philippe Gambette has a [webpag](http://www.lirmm.fr/~gambette/EnsDecompositionModulaireENG.php)e about bibliography of modular decomposition algorithms.

About "A Simple Linear-Time Modular Decomposition Algorithm for Graphs, Using Order Extension", Fabien de Montgolfier provided an extended version of this paper on [his website](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~fm/). If you are interested in variants or generalizations of MD, you can find some papers about Homogeneous Relations in his website, too.

Answer (score 7):

There actually *is* a (relatively) simple recursive modular decomposition algorithm that works in linear time. See: http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~mtedder/TedderModular.pdf

Comment: The algorithm of the paper is for undirected graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Diestel's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198532105). It explains how modular decomposition works and how to apply it. In this book there is also a lot of information about convexity in a graph.